# nuxhash mining on linux for nicehash miner

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, python, software-center

```
 line 38, in request
    raise Exception(str(response.status_code) + ": " + response.reason)
Exception: 404: Not Found
install ocl-icd-libopencl1
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/nuxhash/gui/mining.py", line 140, in do_requests
    wallet, unpaid = get_balances(self._Settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/nuxhash/nicehash.py", line 26, in get_balances
    response = nh.public_api(HOST).request(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/nuxhash/nhrest/python/nicehash.py", line 38, in request
    raise Exception(str(response.status_code) + ": " + response.reason)
Exception: 404: Not Found
```

I get this far with installation then no further any ideas

Answer (score 0):

Nicehash api has been updated
You need to edit /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/nuxhash/nicehash.py and add a "2" to the url

GET main/api/v2/mining/external/{btcAddress}/rigs2

(from https://www.nicehash.com/blog/post/api-changes-notification-apr-3)